# ¿Se debe usar artículo al introducir el objeto directo con "aprender"?

Tags: gramática, artículos, objetos-directos

De las siguientes dos expresiones, ¿cuál es la correcta?

> Tutorial, referencia y ejemplos para aprender **sintaxis** SQL.

> Tutorial, referencia y ejemplos para aprender **la sintaxis** SQL.

Comment: I will let one of the native speakers confirm this but I would use the second but I would insert _de_ before SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se usan verbos como *aprender* o *estudiar*, el objeto directo (aquello que se aprende o estudia, la materia, asignatura, disciplina, técnica, etc.) generalmente va sin artículo definido. También con verbos como *reprobar*:

- *Este año voy a aprender álgebra y cálculo.*
- *Tienes que estudiar gramática para saber escribir un ensayo.*
- *Le fue mal en el examen y reprobó geografía.*

Esto no ocurre con otros verbos, como *dominar*:

- *El año pasado logré dominar el álgebra y el cálculo.*
- *Ella domina totalmente la gramática.*

El artículo sí se debe usar normalmente cuando la materia de estudio es el sujeto:

- *El álgebra y el cálculo son fundamentales para un ingeniero.*
- *La gramática que estudiamos en la escuela no funciona.*

Recordar que la materia de estudio también es el sujeto en oraciones con *gustar* y verbos similares:

- *No me gusta nada el álgebra.*
- *Me encanta la gramática.*
- *A ella le apasiona la geografía.*

Comment: ¿Eso se aplica también si se involucra un complemento preposicional, es decir "la sintaxis de SQL"? Noto que hay varias veces más resultados para "aprender la sintaxis de/del" frente a "aprender sintaxis de/del", además de que "aprender la sintaxis" de por sí tiene más resultados que "aprender sintaxis". Esto igualmente es el caso respecto a "la gramática de/del".

Comment: Sí, me faltó eso (la otra respuesta lo explica mejor). De todas formas, yo diría "aprender sintaxis SQL" o bien "aprender la sintaxis del SQL", como únicas alternativas.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar la buena respuesta de Pablo y en consonancia con el comentario de Obie, cabe agregar que generalmente se usa el artículo cuando la materia de estudio está calificada por un modificador indirecto (introducido por preposición):

- Para aprender **la** gramática **del español** hacen falta varios años.

No obstante, cuando el núcleo y el modificador indirecto forman una unidad (como si fuera el título de la materia), se prescinde del artículo.

- Tienes que estudiar **historia de Roma**.
- Aprobó **geografía de tercer año**.